# Let there be peace and destruction

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, video-games

> I use your Intelligence against you,   If you try to chase me, I
>   confine you,   I am considered omen to bad things,   Don't be scared,
>   sometimes I do good things.

**Guess who am I...**

Hint 1

> Bagen

Hint 2

> Hint 1 is an Anagram

Hint 3

> Eclipse

Comment: i want to say something like rot13(qnexarff)

Comment: @Jordan.J.D Not quite, but i can say the answer to the riddle is related to it.

Comment: Is this a specific game or something related to gaming? You don't need to answer if you think it's gonna give away too much...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel  I will give it as a hint after some time if answer isn’t found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are:

> G-Man from half life

I use your Intelligence against you,

> Uses the fact freeman is a doctor to cause the resonace cascade

If you try to chase me, I confine you,

> When you find G-Man in half life he detains you

I am considered omen to bad things,

> He often shows up before something bad happens

Don't be scared, sometimes I do good things.

> He does also save you a couple of times

Hint 1 and 2:

> Gaben the creator of half-life

Hint 3:

> Eclipse is the name of a mod for half time and could also refer to Black mesa

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not what your original answer.. But here goes.

> You are SLEEP.

Here's the explanation:

> Sleep uses your intelligence against you. Because you can't sleep when you are thinking. If you chase sleep, i.e. you want to sleep you are confined to bed. "Sleeping forever" is a way of describing death, so bad omen. But healthy life demands sleep as well.

Comment: The way I know it's not the answer you're looking for is it does not explain your hint.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for. I still don't get how you can't sleep if you are thinking. I have used the word Intelligence which is not similar to thinking. Nice try though! Upvoted :).

Answer (score 1):

You might be:

> Video games/gaming

I use your Intelligence against you,

> Some games are truely mindf*cks

If you try to chase me, I confine you,

> You can get caught up in them, not allowing you to do the things you were supposed to do, e.g. homework

I am considered omen to bad things,

> Parents often don't like children to play them (for too long), they say that you might not be able to see virtual from real after a long time of playing

Don't be scared, sometimes I do good things.

> Event though gaming is often seen as a bad thing/waste of time, it does very good things to people, including relaxation, sharpness of mind and be able to quickly analize something logically

Hints:

> I think the first hint is an anagram for Gaben, which is often used to refer to Gabe Logan Newell, the president of Steam (the gaming platform). The third hint might be drawn towards an eclipse in game, therefore this could as well be a specific game, than gaming all together. Furthermore, eclipse is a programming IDE, which can be used to create/write games.

Comment: You got the first 2 hints right. The answer was not what I was looking for though. I don’t think gaming uses our intelligence against us. Good try +1. I think with little more thinking you can get the answer as you are close to it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> Superstitions

I use your Intelligence against you,

> From wikipedia: 'Superstition is a pejorative term for any belief or practice that is considered irrational for example, if it arises from ignorance, a misunderstanding of science or causality, a positive belief in fate or magic, or fear of that which is unknown.

If you try to chase me, I confine you,

> if you try to follow a superstition, you will find nothing. If you try to stand against it, everybody will be against you.

I am considered omen to bad things,

> most superstitions are about bad things. A black cat crossing -> bad luck. Opening an umbrella, etc.

Don't be scared, sometimes I do good things.

> Some times superstitions arise to change bad behavior in people.

Comment: Nice try , I don’t think superstitions use your intelligence against you and it doesn’t match with the hints.